# Writing a regex that matches at least x lookahead conditions

Tags: regex, yup

I'm writing validation for a form with `yup`:

```js
const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  password: Yup.string()
    .matches(/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/, {
      message:
        "Must be at least 8 characters long, contain a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter, and a number."
    })
    .min(8, "Must be at least 8 characters long.")
    .matches(/(?=.*[a-z])/, { message: "Must contain a lowercase letter." })
    .matches(/(?=.*[A-Z])/, { message: "Must contain an uppercase letter." })
    .matches(/(?=.*\d)/, { message: "Must contain a number." })
    .required("Password is required."),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
    .oneOf([Yup.ref("password"), null], "Passwords don't match.")
    .required("Password confirmation is required.")
});
```

If there's at least 2 errors, the first validation message should display (`"Must be at least 8 characters long, contain a lowercase letter...`). Otherwise it should fall back to any of the other validation messages.

How can this be done? At the moment the multiple validation error is always being displayed (it should only display if there's at least 2 errors). I'm no master at regex so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to place the overall check as the last of the `matches` statements?

Comment: Why do you need the many lookaheads at all? I'd do something [like this demo](https://tio.run/##hcu7DoJQDADQ/X5FZQESgcGFBB34DR9D5ZaHaSihFRN/Ho2bMLCf88AJtRq7wZJePM3zhCMonCDEe1npwdfq67BwrqsjTZn6xlo4Qh47gEp6FaaUpYkCEwFtZbQ95IAGTKgWxIUjVoLv3mVXn6VGapHGq94TefBd09nuP10wed82HsuLRkAeWlzuMjlv7ecwrPYSIjM0Iv4H3Dx/AA) or [for 2 errors at most](https://tio.run/##jY27DoJAEEV7vmKg4JEIJFYkauFviMSMMAJmZTc7Ayb@PKIRGwtsT@4594oDcmlbI3GnKxrHAS0w7CDAcxlsHEeRAFl7unE90byYUHsJOVHU1dLAFrLIgXmRmJ6b0BOtgRttZQUZoIAiZPGizct00xzjR5EmQiwhR792R1SB0neygMo06H7McJ59r9cR@D5MxX18WCz2xvxfPFZLuaqtW3mHnFJ3rBUlStdzccLj@AQ).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep and it's the same problem except in reverse. It'll show the individual errors until they're all fixed (and by the time they're all fixed the regex for multiple errors no longer has a match)

Comment: @bobblebubble it's a requirement from the design team. That conditional logic is doable with JS, but how do you do so with `yup` and regex alone?